# onlyOwner modifier works in truffle test but not in console

Tags: modifiers

In the following code, the console.log returns an empty string, but the truffle test works fine!

```
const certificate = contract(Certificate);
certificate.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
var certificateInstance = 
certificate.at("0xfcdf59a5e2a43059d3d469f4aa31534d6c0d00b7");
return certificateInstance
    .ownerName() // state variable in the contract
    .then(function(_ownerName) {
      console.log(_ownerName);
      // getParam2 is the function with onlyOwner modifier
      return certificateInstance.getParam2({ from: owner });
    })
    .then(function(_value) {
      console.log(_value);
    });
```

Below are my truffle test code:

```
...
return Certificate.at(certAddress);
}).then(function(instance){
    certInstance = instance;
    return certInstance.getParam2({from: owner});
}).then(function(_value){
    assert.equal(_value, "param2value", "modifier function returns correct value"
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check out this [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call)

You should `call` as in that example. E.g:

```
return certificateInstance
   .ownerName
   .call()
   .then( ...
```

Comment: Truffle has a different syntaxis than web3.js v1 more like web3.js v0.20.

Comment: @Ismael that's correct, but how it's related to my answer. In question it's being asked why this is not working in browser with web3 & I replied why.